# SDL tiles rendering

Tags: tiles, sdl

I'm pretty new to SDL and wonder what is better if I have to draw tiled map on screen: to SDL_RenderCopy each tile from texture(which presents tileset) and then SDL_RenderPresent it every frame or to compose somehow map onto another texture which will be rendered every frame?

Comment: I agree with XiaoChuan Yu, it's probably not a big deal. If you find it to be a bottleneck then you can start thinking of new ways to draw tiles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably better to just call SDL_RenderCopy multiple times and copy to display buffer directly rather than composing and uploading an extra texture to GPU which in the end you copy to display buffer anyways.